# Need to take snapshots in X11using imLib2 library

Tags: linux, x11, embedded-linux

Hi we need to take a snapshots of current running application window when we click a button. This should be done automatically in code. For this we used Imlib2 library and use the following api's imlib_create_image_from_drawable and imlib_copy_drawable_to_image. This is the code we used to take snapshots but it doesn't work please help us thank in advance.

```
Imlib_Image buffer;
buffer = imlib_create_image_from_drawable(pixmap, 0, 0, glb.windowWidth, glb.windowHeight, 0); 
imlib_context_set_image(buffer);
imlib_copy_drawable_to_image(pixmap, 0, 0, glb.windowWidth, glb.windowHeight, 0, 0, 0);
imlib_context_set_image(buffer);
imlib_image_set_format("png");
imlib_save_image("screenshot");
imlib_free_image();
```

Comment: "it doesn't work". You forgot to insert a description of the problem after these words.

Comment: Our need is to take snapshots of running application. For this we had written the above code. First i had created a Pixmap and copied our application window to Pixmap using XCopyArea api. Then passed the Pixmap variable to the above function. In this function i had created a image from this pixmap and set the current image and copied the pixmap to the image. Again set the image and format for saving the image and finally saved the image using imlib_save_image api but it doesn't work. can you please help what i had done wrong in the above sample? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your description of the code is far less useful than the code itself would be. You forgot to insert a description of the problem again. I hope someone can help you.

Comment: The above code is not working to take snapshots of running application. Please tell us what mistake i had done in the above sample or please help how to take a snapshots of running application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you. I had corrected my code and i can able to take snapshot of running application using Imlib library. In the above i forget to set the drawable. This is the corrected code and it works fine

```
Imlib_Image buffer;

buffer = imlib_create_image(glb.windowWidth, glb.windowHeight); 
imlib_context_set_image(buffer);
imlib_context_set_display(display);
imlib_context_set_visual(DefaultVisual(display, 0));
imlib_context_set_drawable(window);
imlib_copy_drawable_to_image(0, 0, 0, glb.windowWidth, glb.windowHeight, 0, 0, 1);
imlib_context_set_image(buffer);
imlib_image_set_format("png");
imlib_save_image("screenshot");
imlib_free_image();
```